# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'expandtabs' | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, chatbot

I was trying to make an command which flips a coin and returns embed message.
I am kinda new to this. So, try to help me out

Code:

```
 @ client.command(description=['Flips coin'])
async def coinflip(ctx):
    responses = ("Heads", "Tails")
    bots_answer = random.choices(responses)

    em = discord.Embed(title="Coinflip",
                       description=f"{ctx.author}flipped a coin", color=0x161716)

    em.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author}flipped a coin. Logging from {ctx.guild.name}",
                  image_url="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/pixel-art-skull-head-planet_41992-1624.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.1269312061.1649929831")

    em.add_field(text=f"It's ***{bots_answer}***")
    em.set_thumbnail(url="https://acegif.com/wp-content/gifs/coin-flip-49.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

And when I run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Kunnu\Discord.py\temp.py", line 124, in <module>
    async def coinflip(ctx):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1262, in decorator
    result = command(*args, **kwargs)(func)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1433, in decorator
    return cls(func, name=name, **attrs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.description = inspect.cleandoc(kwargs.get('description', ''))
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\inspect.py", line 750, in cleandoc
    lines = doc.expandtabs().split('\n')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Comment: `expandtabs` is in the discord.py library as seen in the traceback. In my opinion, the code sample given was sufficient. (See my answer)

Answer (score 2):

The error is contained with in this decorator.

```py
@client.command(description=['Flips coin'])
```

[The description is supposed to be a string.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.description)

Change it to:

```py
@client.command(description='Flips coin')
```

If you want to have multiple descriptions for different uses, you can also define [`brief`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.usage) or [`usage`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.brief) or [`help`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.help).